# Arrow keys and enter key is not working together in js

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have used the bootstrap select in an angular project. This select is working with the arrow keys and also the enter key. Arrow keys make the selection up/down and enter key select the value. But both of the functions are not working together at the same time. here is the code-

```
var listOfDropDownItems = element.find('.dropdown-menu');
element.bind('keydown', function (evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode === 40 || evt.keyCode === 38) {
    // listOfDropDownItems.scrollTop = listOfDropDownItems.scrollTop + 24;
    listOfDropDownItems.scrollTop;
  }
});
```

/* If I comment this above code the following will work and vice-versa. */

```
function hitEnter(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    // alert('Enter Pressed');
    $('.dropdown-item.active .dropdown-item-inner').click();
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', hitEnter);
document.addEventListener('keyup', hitEnter);
```

Comment: you are overwriting the code below with the code above, and vice versa

Comment: How can I make both functions working?